# Using Case in WHERE condition MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Is it possible to use CASE statement in WHERE condition like below?

```
SELECT act.id_activity FROM activity act
LEFT JOIN work w ON w.id_work = act.id_work
WHERE 
w.work_type=1
AND w.work_tender in (1,2)
AND act.id_activity_type IN 
(CASE WHEN w.work_tender=1 THEN '2,3' WHEN w.work_tender=2 THEN '2,3,4,9' END)
```

it returns no error but the results always display act.id_activity_type = 2 instead of 2,3 or 2,3,4,9

In this case 1 work (table work) can have many activities (table activity). i want to display activities based on work.work_tender type. if work.work_tender=1 then need to choose activity.id_activity_type IN (2,3). if work.work_tender=2 then need to choose activity.id_activity_type IN (2,3,4,9)

Comment: I think you should put that in `SELECT` instead. By the way, there's not point in doing `LEFT JOIN` when you're going to do a `WHERE` on table columns other than the most left table-unless you're extracting `NULL`, non-matching values. Otherwise, it's just turning your query into a `JOIN`.

Comment: Also, `WHERE 
AND w.work_type=1` is erroneous

Comment: Hi @FanoFN. thanks for highligting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write correct logic by `OR` & `AND`.

```
SELECT act.id_activity FROM activity act
LEFT JOIN work w ON w.id_work = act.id_work
WHERE 
w.work_type=1
AND (
    (act.id_activity_type IN ('2','3') AND w.work_tender=1) OR 
    (act.id_activity_type IN ('2','3','4','9') AND w.work_tender=2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think case is used for that case. I think it is possible to use in that case. And also for orderby phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activity a 
JOIN work w
ON w.work_tender=
   CASE WHEN a.id_activity_type IN (2,3) THEN 1
        WHEN a.id_activity_type IN (2,3,4,9) THEN 2 END;
```

I'm using `CASE` expression here to assign value matching `w.work_tender` if the `a.id_activity_type` fit the condition. So, if `a.id_activity_type IN (2,3) THEN 1` will match with `w.work_tender=1` similarly with `a.id_activity_type IN (2,3,4,9) THEN 2` will match with `w.work_tender=2`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eebc974147014215e960dfd1a73dc3f4)